# Simple swift delegate in swift playground

Tags: swift, delegates

I'm very new to Swift and programming in general, a bit of Fortran 77 way back, and more recently some simple programming of microcontrollers. I'm working through the basics and all was well until i came across something that i just can't quite get to grips with - delegates. All the online posts don't quite get the concept across, at least for me, so to give myself something that i can refer back to, i've set up a basic template shown below in playground. If i run the code below it works and prints "Something done" to the terminal, but if i make the protocol a "class" protocol ie "protocol SomeDelegate: class {" and make the "var delegate" a "weak var delegate" as recommended in various posts, it doesn't work - what am i doing wrong?

```
import UIKit

protocol SomeDelegate {
    func DoSomething()
}

class MyViewcontroller: UIViewController, SomeDelegate {

    func DoSomething() {
        print("Something done")
    }

}


class OtherClass {

   var delegate: SomeDelegate?


    func DoSomething() {

        delegate?.DoSomething()

    }
}


var myVar = OtherClass()
myVar.delegate = MyViewcontroller()
myVar.DoSomething()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't print because the delegate is nil right after you set it. The reason for this is simple: no instance owns it (the reference count is zero). No one owns `delegate` because you declared it a weak property of OtherClass. Try establishing an ownership, e.g.

```
var myVar = OtherClass()
let viewController = MyViewController()
myVar.delegate = viewController
```

Even though delegate is weak, it will now print `Something done` again.

Declaring delegates as weak makes sense because it prevents circular references causing delegate to never be release in memory – that's a whole different story though – check how reference counting works, then you will understand why this is a good practice.